# How to filter Multiselect in Magento 2 search Rest API?

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, multiselect-attribute, search-criteria

I am using magento search rest api. Now i can filter attributes like neck, sleeve, etc.., but i need to give multiple values for same attribute (like mulitple select)

**My Request:**

```
rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=18
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=filter_color
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=20
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][field]=filter_color
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][value]=22
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][conditionType]=eq
```

when multiselect the same attribute(filter_color) it gives the last filter values(for filter_color= 22) only.

And when i am using `conditionType = IN like
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=filter_color
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=20, 22
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=in`
 it gives the result of 0 record. So how to get both attributes filtered items and its aggregation

Comment: Please Help me.

Comment: I have one product with two color white,blue.when I call searchCriteria API,this product is not showing in response.

Answer (score 2):

Your are using wrong filter for Search using REST endpoints condition_type type should be

```
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=in it gives the result of 0 record. So
```

Used **finset** A value within a set of values form multiselect

```
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=finset
```